# git server and django program inside nginx

Tags: django, git, nginx, gunicorn, git-server

I want to run a git server inside my django program. my nginx config is like this:

```
server{
    listen 192.168.1.250:80;

    root /var/www/html/git;            

    location /server\.git {           

        client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
        auth_basic "Git Login"; # Whatever text will do.
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/html/git/htpasswd";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include the default fastcgi configs
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend; # Tells fastcgi to pass the request to the git http backend executable
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/html/git; # /var/www/git is the location of all of your git repositories.
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1; # Takes the capture group from our location directive and gives git that.
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; # Pass the request to fastcgi
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.250:8000;            
    }

}
```

my django program run correctly, but for git server, I cannot open that.

but when I change the location of django program, both of them work correctly.

```
location /user {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://192.168.1.250:8000;            
}
```

I want to use just "/" and not to "/" + string. what should I do??